# EPPlus and Excel's Camera Tool

Tags: c#, epplus

Is it possible to use Excel's Camera Tool with EPPlus? that is: programatically copy a range of cells from one sheet and paste them as a drawing object into another sheet?

**Update:**

I noticed that Excel's Camera Tool simply creates a picture with a formula. The formula is the range of cells to be watched/observed by Excel. If any of these cells change the picture is updated by Excel.

But with EPPlus is not possible to inject a formula to a Picture object, eg:

```
var picture = worksheet.Drawings.AddPicture("picture", (FileInfo)null);
picture.SetPosition(1, 0, 1, 0);
picture.Formula = "A1:D9"; // ...there is no "Formula" property for ExcelPicture object
```

Any workaround?

Comment: My opinion is that it's not possible with EPPlus (without modifying its source code), because it just doesn't know about camera tool and does not emit required xml when saving file.

Answer (score 1):

Bad news when I record a VBA Macro and replay it, it doesn't work. This is the syntax thats generated:

```
Range("A2").Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(, 355.5, 32.25, 72#, 72#).Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 3")).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Working with Images in Excel via automation is limited. You are pretty much limited to Shapes (or *shudder* - clipboard):

```
Set shp = ws.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\You.png", msoFalse, msoTrue, l, t, w, h)
shp.Name = strPic
shp.ScaleHeight Factor:=1, RelativeToOriginalSize:=msoTrue
shp.ScaleWidth Factor:=1, RelativeToOriginalSize:=msoTrue
```

What I am suggesting is create a screenshot of the selected cell and workaround it that way.

```
'Select the cells you want to copy to image
Range("A2").Select
'Copy selected cells contents to clipboard as image
Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
'Choose destination
Range("B3").Select
'Paste
ActiveSheet.Paste

'Restore previous clipboard to memory
```

Hopefully the above will be enough to help you get it working in EPPPlus.

ps Converting VBA to C# is really easy, and it should be 
 trivial converting the above to EPPPlus: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34055947/495455

Comment: Except EPPlus works with office open xml, not interops with excel.

Comment: I know, ok give me some time and I'll convert it.